# POST JSON data to specific object iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, json, post

I have read several posts on Stack about how to POST data using both XML and JSON however nothing is standing out to me about how to update a selected object.

I am pulling down data from my boss' job tracking API fine, all things are accounted for. However I want to update individual selected object's variables.

Example:

> If I have a recipe site API and I am pulling down 100 recipes and displaying the titles in a table. I select a row and it displays a new screen which shows all the details about the recipe with textfields for updating content and a button that will save to the website. **How do I update an ingredient on the selected recipe so that it is represented on the website?**

Bare in mind I am using my business' API and not Parse.com or another server based database.

I would prefer to use JSON however if there are better solutions using XML I am fine with that.

**New Thought**

Do I have to replace the entire object when updating?

**More Info**

Due to using an API, I do not have links directly to a specific object. I get given the block (100 recipes), have to iterate through the block to save each object as NSObject and then sort the newly stored NSObjects how I like to. When I select a row, I am selecting an object that has been sorted and displaying that objects contents. I don't know if this information is helpful or not.

The reason for this extra information is:

**When trying to update the Object through the API, how do I know I am updating that specific object and not the entire list of objects?**

Comment: you can POST the data onto the existing field

Comment: @T_77 Do you have an example by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to POST data onto the existing fields:

You can try this to POST the data:

```
 NSString  *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text_field1=%@",text_field.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://your api to recieve the data into the fields"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn) {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }
    }
```

Comment: I have something similar to that however it scares me to think that I may do it across the entire database rather than the selected field ;-) May have to bite the bullet though.

Comment: I am confused because I do not know **how does the API know which "recipe" I have selected in order to update the variable of ingredient?** Is it meant to be contained within the URL or?

Comment: Put all recipes in one table and give ID for each recipe.....so your url should be something like : [http://recipie/ID=%@,text_field.text];

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me. I have WHERE and ORDER clauses in the API and they are not responding via the app. They work fine when testing in a browser though. Will try work it out. Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Mantle on GitHub.
https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle